# S3 uploads corrupt file when using stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, socket.io

I've built a chat server using rails, socket.io, and node that allows users to send images to each other, which I'm trying to get to work with Amazon s3. Here are the relevant code snippets from the client and server:

Client:

```
var img_file = this.files[0]; //retrieved from file input

file_reader.onload = function(e) {
    //console.log(img_file);
    var extension = img_file.name.split('.');
    extension = extension[extension.length-1];


    get_user_id(username, function(to_id) {
        socket.emit('message', {
            from: "<%= @user.displayname %>",
            fromid: <%= @user.id %>,
            to: username,
            toid: parseInt(to_id),
            content: e.target.result,
            type: 'image',
            extension: extension,
            size: img_file.size
        });
    })

};

file_reader.readAsBinaryString(img_file);
```

Server:

```
socket.on('message', function(message) {
    console.log(message.type + " message received, sending to appropriate person: " + message.to);
    if (message.type == 'text') {
        //send message like normal
        sendMessage(message);           
    }
    else {
        //it's an image, need additional processing

        var blank_file = uuid.v4() + '-' + new Date().getTime() + '.' + message.extension;
        var contents = message.content;

        s3.putObject({
            Bucket: 'bucket-name', //not the real bucket name
            Key: blank_file,
            ContentType: 'image/' + message.extension,
            //ContentLength: message.size,
            Body: contents
        },
        function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
            else {
                console.log('file uploaded to s3 successfully');

                message.content = getS3Url(blank_file);

                sendMessage(message);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to upload an image using this code, it appears to work, but when I check my s3 bucket and open up the image, my operating system says that the file is unreadable or corrupt. I've tried using the ContentLength parameter but when I use that I get the error "BadDigest: The Content-MD5 you specified did not match what we received."

Can anyone help me out? I got this code to work properly *without* s3, but for some reason I keep getting corrupt or unrecognizable files since I started using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. You need to use a binary buffer to pass the data to s3 instead of just passing the string as is, so basically use these for the s3 parameters:

```
s3.putObject({
    Bucket: 'bucket-name',
    Key: file,
    Body: new Buffer(contents, 'binary') //use a buffer to pass the data over
}, function() { });
```

By using the buffer, it should upload the files properly.